# AngularJS error [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: in IE11

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I couldn't find help in Google or here either. I'm new to Angular and I'm facing this error only in IE11 and below.

The error I'm getting is this:
[image: console error shown in IE]

**My IE is in Portuguese** so the translate of the first error is: *it's not possible to get property of "getAttribute" of undefined or null*

this is my app.config.js file

```js
// Checking if an optional module is registered.
// If it's not, register an empty one to prevent errors.
(function(optDeps){
    optDeps.forEach(function(dep){
        try{
            angular.module(dep);
        }catch(e){
            angular.module(dep, []);
        }
    })
})(['ui.carousel', 'ui.mask', 'vAccordion', 'ngAnimate']);

angular

.module('poletto', [
    // Third party
    'smoothScroll',
    'ui.carousel',
    'ui.mask',
    'vAccordion',
    'ngAnimate',
    
    // Components
    'poletto.components',

    // Controllers
    'poletto.controllers',

    // Directives
    'poletto.directives',

    // Factories
    'poletto.factories',

    // Filters
    'poletto.filters',

    // Services
    'poletto.services'
])

.constant('CONSTANTS', {
    BASE_URL: document.currentScript.getAttribute('data-base-url')
})

.config(function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
})

.config(function($locationProvider){
    if(window.history.pushState){
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false, rewriteLinks: false });
    }
})

// Extending JQLite with a function that find nodes by className
.run(function(){
    angular.element.prototype.findBySelector = function(selector){
        var matches = [];
        
        for(key in this){
            // Pushing only HTMLElement's
            if(this[key].nodeType){
                // NodeList to array
                var results = Array.prototype.slice.call(this[key].querySelectorAll(selector));

                matches.push.apply(matches, results);
            }
        }

        return angular.element(matches);
    };
})
```

I've searched google and tried some solutions such as:

- add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />`
- wrap all my declarations in:

```
(function (angular) {
    "use strict";
    //code
}(window.angular));
```

- add this in html tag:

```
<html lang="pt-br" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
```

- Also I couldn't find any angular polyfills neither src/ folder, which I saw in a similar question with angular 2.

I don't know which file I should put here, so if you need some more info, you can ask me and I update the question.

Comment: Lenilson's answer is more fulfilling, so I suggest you mark that as the accepted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately [`document.currentScript` is not supported on IE](https://caniuse.com/#search=currentScript) and can't be polyfilled so it can't done that way. Perhaps, you can embed the base url somewhere else or maybe add an `id` to your script and retrieve it in old school javascript.

```
<script id="main" data-base-url="https://my-api.com"></script>
```

And then retrieve it like this:

```
var currentScript = document.getElementById('main');
```

In your `CONSTANTS` provider you can do something like this:

```
.constant('CONSTANTS', {
    BASE_URL: document.getElementById('main').getAttribute('data-base-url')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem stems from using `document.currentScript`, which isn't supported in IE 11 and apparently can't be polyfilled (easily at least). So you'll have to find a different way to declare your `BASE_URL` constant.