# AngularJS error [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: in IE11 with Minified JS

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs and want cross browser compatbility. It works fine in Chrome and firefox but in IE11 it is giving.
[image]

```js
angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('AgencyFactory', AgencyFactory)
  .factory('AdminService', adminService);
adminService.$inject = ['$resource'];


function adminService($resource) {
  return {
    UpdateLeadStatus:

      $resource('/Agency/UpdateLeadStatus/Ids/:Ids/StatusId/:StatusId/ProducerId/:ProducerId', {}, {
        change: {
          method: 'POST',
          params: {},
          isArray: false
        }
      }),
    AssignProducer: $resource('/Agency/AssignProducer/AutoAssign/:AutoAssign', {}, {
      change: {
        method: 'POST',
        params: {},
        isArray: false
      }
    }),
    UpdateProducerAssignedStatus: $resource('/Agency/UpdateProducerAssignedStatus/Ids/:Ids/Status/:Status/AutoAssign/:AutoAssign', {}, {
      change: {
        method: 'POST',
        params: {},
        isArray: false
      }
    }),


  };
}


AgencyFactory.$inject = ['AdminService', '$uibModal', 'modalService', '$rootScope'];

function AgencyFactory(AdminService, $uibModal, modalService, $rootScope) {



  function UpdateLeadStatus(Ids, StatusId, ProducerId) {
    return AdminService.UpdateLeadStatus.change({
      Ids: Ids,
      StatusId: StatusId,
      ProducerId: ProducerId
    }).$promise;
  }

  function AssignProducer(AutoAssign) {
    return AdminService.AssignProducer.change({
      AutoAssign: AutoAssign
    }).$promise;
  }

  function UpdateProducerAssignedStatus(Ids, Status, AutoAssign) {

    return AdminService.UpdateProducerAssignedStatus.change({
      Ids: Ids,
      Status: Status,
      AutoAssign: AutoAssign
    }).$promise;
  }

  return {


    UpdateLeadStatus: UpdateLeadStatus,
    AssignProducer: AssignProducer,
    UpdateProducerAssignedStatus: UpdateProducerAssignedStatus,
  };
}
})();
```

When I use un-minified code it works fine, but when I minify it, it shows the Error

Comment: Is this the whole code in which is being used dependency injection? If not, you better check the whole source code looking for a missing dependency injection.

Comment: This might be a stupid answer from me but have you tried to declare your service AdminService first ? angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('AdminService', adminService)
  .factory('AgencyFactory', AgencyFactory); instead of  angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('AdminService', adminService)
  .factory('AgencyFactory', AgencyFactory);

Comment: Don't n know it might work or not but you can refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46891527/angularjs-error-injectorunpr-unknown-provider-in-ie11

Comment: I already went through this link,